# Wireless Keyboard Issues

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I seem to be having a problem with my keyboard. My Draconic (K530RGB) keyboard that I got two months was working great both wired and wireless until yesterday. My problem now is that wherever I turn on the switch, all three bluetooth modes are undiscoverable and the LED on the side is off. The keyboard itself will do the power on animation and then go blank. Pressing any key will make the backlight light up for a second and then go blank again. Switching the bluetooth mode to 1, 2, or 3 still does not light up the LED. To ensure its not the battery I've even tried while it was plugged in and with a solid green LED on the power indicator. This problem started when I used the update tool that came with the software so I'm wondering if maybe it's the firmware or something else. Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Edit: I've contacted support twice with no return of any messages. Also, the switch I'm talking about is the one for power. There are two switches, one that turns on the keyboards bluetooth and one for selecting which of the three bluetooth connections you want to use. The power switch should be off for wired use though if you want to use bluetooth while charging from a computer the power switch will disable the USB control and enable bluetooth.

Comment: "wherever I turn on the switch, all three bluetooth modes are undiscoverable" What switch? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the information to hopefully help with the cause.